# Как реализовать историю изменений таблицы?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть задача: реализовать журнал правок для этой таблицы:
[image: Таблица]
Должна быть возможность вносить изменения для нескольких полей за одну правку, возможность откатить изменения.

**Вопрос:** как хранить историю этих правок в базе данных?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение задачи по хранению истории зависит от таких факторов, как время хранения, объем данных, скорость записи, количество таблиц, поддержка изменения структуры таблиц и др. Поэтому совсем универсального решения нет.

Многие БД поддерживают технологию Flashback, это когда  можно просматривать данные, какими они были некоторое время назад. Обычно для этого требуется значительное место для хранения и технология чувствительна к изменению структуры таблиц.

Если требуется хранения только истории представленной таблицы, то простыми решениями будут следующие:

1. Хранить данные в этой же таблице, добавив столбец со ссылкой на предыдущую запись. Плюсом будет нечувствительность к изменению структуры, минусы - избыточность, т.к. будут каждый раз храниться все поля, даже те которые не изменялись, сложная обработка по сравнению и восстановлению данных.
2. Хранить данные в практически идентичной таблице, со ссылкой на основную таблицу и возможностью хранения всех полей пустыми. Плюсы  и минусы противоположны предыдущему решению.
3. Хранить данные в таблице поле-значение. Плюсы не требует отслеживать изменение структуры, минусы отсутствие типизации и поддержки обработки некоторых типов полей, например `BLOB`.

Простым и универсальным способом отслеживания изменений будут триггеры для таблицы на вставку, изменение, удаление. Про возможность изменения нескольких полей я не очень понял.

Answer (score 1):

Надо смотреть триггеры(хранимые процедуры) на события по той базе данных, что вы используете. Если такая архитектура не противоречит удобству развёртывания новых копий приложения и разработке.